# Push Object property values to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

To convert the object into arrays based on the number of keys present inside the JSON object using JS.

**the actual Object**

```
  values: [
        {
          Label: "label1",
          Value: "10",
        },
        {
          Label: "label2",
          Value: "11",
        },
        {
          Label: "label3",
          Value: "12",
        },
      ],
    };
```

And I want the actual output to be something like this

```
label:['label1','label2','label3']
value:['10','11','12']
```

Using javascript or in react.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` function of the array and return Label and Values from the input array.

```js
let  values = [
        {
          Label: "label1",
          Value: "10",
        },
        {
          Label: "label2",
          Value: "11",
        },
        {
          Label: "label3",
          Value: "12",
        },
      ]

let value = values.map(v => v.Value)
let label = values.map(v => v.Label)

console.log(value)
console.log(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most intuitive way to do this is just using two `for` loops, like this, that automatically construct the object as they go. The benefit of this answer is that it works for an object with any number of different keys -- no key names are hard-coded, so it's completely adaptable.

```js
const values = {
  values: [{
      Label: "label1",
      Value: "10",
    },
    {
      Label: "label2",
      Value: "11",
    },
    {
      Label: "label3",
      Value: "12",
    },
  ]
}

let ret = {};

// For each object,
for (let val of values.values) {
  // And each key in each object,
  for (let key in val) {
    // If the key is not in the return object, create an array there,
    if (!ret[key]) ret[key] = [];
    // and then push the value into the array.
    ret[key].push(val[key]);
  }
}

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array of objects, and use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to extract the information.

```js
const values = [{Label:"label1",Value:"10"},{Label:"label2",Value:"11"},{Label:"label3",Value:"12"}];

const out = values.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  // Object.values returns an array
  const [ label, value ] = Object.values(obj);

  // Push the data into the initial (accumulator) object
  acc.label.push(label);
  acc.value.push(value);

  // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
  return acc;

// The initial object that is returned with each iteration
}, { label: [], value: [] });

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach like following

```
 let  values = [
        {
          Label: "label1",
          Value: "10",
        },
        {
          Label: "label2",
          Value: "11",
        },
        {
          Label: "label3",
          Value: "06",
        },
         {
          Label: "label4",
          Value: "25",
        }
      ]
      let valueArray =[]
      let labels =[]
      values.forEach((value)=>{
      valueArray.push(value.Value)
      labels.push(value.Label) 
      })
       
     let finalObject = {label:labels,value:valueArray}
console.log(valueArray)
console.log(labels)
console.log(finalObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
    values: [
        {
            Label: "label1",
            Value: "10",
        },
        {
            Label: "label2",
            Value: "11",
        },
        {
            Label: "label3",
            Value: "12",
        }
    ]
};

let output = {
    label: [],
    value: []
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.values)) {
    output.label.push(value.Label)
    output.value.push(value.Value)
}

console.log("output::", output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the objects in a single pass:

```js
const values = [ { Label: "label1", Value: "10", }, { Label: "label2", Value: "11", }, { Label: "label3", Value: "12", } ];

let reduced =  values.reduce((total, curr) => {
    total.label.push(curr.Label)
    total.value.push(curr.Value)

    return total
}, {"label": [], "value": []})

console.log(reduced.label)
console.log(reduced.value)
```